# Inserting data into table_name as php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking table name as php variable to insert data into table.
But it gives error. What's bad here?

```
            if($flag == 1)
                $table = 'frrole_pupolar_article';
            else
                $table = 'frrole_category_article';
            $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO '.$table.' (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`, `title` ,`time`,`img_url`,`rt_count`,`tweet_count`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$setiment."','".$category."','".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."')";
```

error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.frrole_category_article.' (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`, `title` ,`time`,`im' at line 1
```

Comment: No dots: `$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO $table ( ..."`

Comment: **if** all your columns **and** values **are** the same why are you putting this in different tables? just add a 'type' column and make your $table = type. I don't see why you need to have same data types in diff tables. Re think your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO '" .$table. "' (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`, `title` ,`time`,`img_url`,`rt_count`,`tweet_count`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$setiment."','".$category."','".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."')";
```

You wrongly written `'.$table.'` instead of `'" .$table. "'`

Comment: thanks but still gives error 'Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''frrole_category_article' (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`, `title` , `time` , `i' at line 1'

Comment: `$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO '" .$table. "' (url, sentiment, category, title, time, img_url, rt_count, tweet_count) VALUES ('".$url."','".$setiment."','".$category."','".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."','".$tweet_count."')";` try this

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO $table (`url`, `sentiment`, `category`, 
                `title` ,`time`,`img_url`,`rt_count`,`tweet_count`) 
                 VALUES ('".$url."','".$setiment."','".$category."',
                 '".$title."','".$time."','".$img_url."','".$rt_count."',
                 '".$tweet_count."')";
```

remove the concatenations and single quotes

Comment: it says : `Error: Table 'mysql.frrole_category_article' doesn't exist`

Comment: remove `mysql.` out of your table name `frrole_category_article`

Answer (score 0):

If your string is `$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO '.$table.' (`url`,`sentiment`,`
You cannot escape it by using single quotes `'..'`

Just do double quotes:

```
$insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`url`, `sentiment`, ....
```

*also* for all that is holy, use damn `{}` for `if(){}` statements, not using them is *poor form*

Comment: Not if you have to read the code afterwards and everything is a mess.

Comment: it says `Error: Table 'mysql.frrole_category_article' doesn't exist` though table exist